# Erro ao usar uma função dentro de array em PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou usando o `laravel 5.2` e na minha classe `IndexController` estou tentando criar um array com a função `date('Y')` assim:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class IndexController extends Controller
{   
    var $arr = array('ano' => date('Y'),
                     'titulo' => 'Titulo do projeto');

    public function Index()
    {        
        //passo o array para a view.       
        return view('welcome')->with($arr);
    }
}
```

mas está me retornando o seguinte erro:

> syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'

Alguém sabe o motivo? estou fazendo algo de errado?

Comment: Tira a palavra `var` isso daí pode dar erro, porque é do PHP 4. Lavarel funciona só com PHP 5+

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema é que você está tentando criar um array com um valor não literal Provavelmente seria melhor usar um membro da classe, em vez de tentar criar um valor que depende de função dentro do `array`.

Como você não explicou exatamente como vai usar o `$arr`, não sei se isso serve, mas segue um pequeno exemplo de como inicializar um dado no construtor da função:

```
class MinhaClasse
{   
    public $arr = array();

    function __construct() {
        $this->arr['ano'] = date('Y');
    }

    public function getAno()
    {              
        return $this->arr['ano'];
    }
}
```

No entanto, isso gera um efeito colateral, que pode ser visto no IDEONE:

> http://ideone.com/gnqcuC

Como o valor pode mudar a cada instanciamento do objeto, provavelmente não é isso que você quer. Seria legal especificar em que momento de fato você vai precisar do valor, pois talvez seja o caso de `static`, ou de passar o valor no construtor. Caso vá usar `static`, precisa de um `if( isset( ) )` no construtor, caso você não queira alterar o valor de todas as instâncias e manter a primeira ocorrência apenas (acho que deixa o código um bocado "inseguro" inclusive, a não ser que você tenha um domínio profundo do que está fazendo).

O `var`, no PHP 5 ele é sinônimo de `public`, mas dá um *warning* (ou erro, se você trabalhar com modo STRICT).

Talvez a solução seja não colocar o ano na criação da classe, mas sim definir no PHP na hora de usá-la mesmo:

```
class MinhaClasse
{   
    public $arr = array();

    public function setAno( $ano ) {
        $this->arr['ano'] = $ano;
    }

    public function getAno()
    {              
        return $this->arr['ano'];
    }
}
```

E na hora de usar:

```
$objeto = new MinhaClasse();
$objeto->setAno( date( 'Y' ) );
// agora vc usa o objeto onde precisar
```

Comment: Mas desse modo você nem precisaria declarar `$arr`. Se você fosse chamar a propriedade da classe dentro do construtor, deveria usar `$this->` ou `self::` (estático). No exemplo, `var $arr = array()` não serve a nenhum propósito.

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida arrumei, é a pressa de responder sem testar, somada a mexer com um monte de linguagem. Ainda mais que PHP eu passo longe de OOP sempre que posso, pelo overhead quase nunca compensar.

Comment: Só mais uma modificação pra ficar perfeito: tira o `echo` e coloca um `return`. Não se deve colocar efeitos colaterais (impressão, `ini_set()`) em código de declaração como numa classe ou função.

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida na verdade eu pus um demo do "defeito" que isso causa no IDEONE, mas vou acatar sua idéia pra ficar melhor pro-forma. Resta saber se o OP precisa mesmo dessa informação em cada instância, ou só na primeira (aí seria o caso de alguma gambiarra no construtor, tipo `if( isset() )`

Comment: Agora, sim!!! +1

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida na verdade eu ainda nao tou satisfeito kkk, preciso saber como o MeuChapeu vai usar essa informação, senão fica a sensação de resposta "meia-boca" largada no site :)

Comment: @Bacco, quero usar a informação que está contina no array para passar para a view do laravel, no caso vai ter outros valores além do ano.. so que quando fui fazer começo dar esse erro..

Comment: @MeuChapeu não seria o caso de setar o ano na chamada em vez de por dentro da classe? Por exemplo, antes de passar pro laravel, usar um método `$meuObjeto->setAno( 2016 )`? Pus um exemplo na resposta

Comment: @Bacco, acho que não pois vai ser usado dentro da classe, acrescentei na resposta outro valor ao array e coloquei como passo o array para a view...